# listening https traffic in nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, reverse-proxy

I need to listening  https traffic, which my code I Can listening all http traffic, but which https I can't capture. How can I do it?
This is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
var url_part = url.parse(request.url,true);
var originUrl = url_part.href;
var options = url.parse(originUrl);
var proxy = http.request(options);
proxy.addListener('response', function (proxy_response) {
    proxy_response.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
       response.write(chunk, 'binary');        
    });
    proxy_response.addListener('end', function() {
       response.end();
    });
    response.writeHead(proxy_response.statusCode, proxy_response.headers);
 });
 request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    proxy.write(chunk, 'application/json');

 });
 request.addListener('end', function() {
    proxy.end();
 });
 }).listen(3128);
```

Comment: use `https` module, please refer doc https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener

Comment: Hi, I already to use https module. This is my code
Sorry it to long I send it to this link
https://pastebin.com/9qgiSc1g
But when I Connect to proxy server with ip, port it say ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE how can I fix it?

Comment: I can not see `https` module, you are using `http`

Comment: @ArifKhan I alredy to use another code, this is my code 
https://pastebin.com/9qgiSc1g 
please seen it again

Comment: What is problem, you can listen http and https both at same time but different port

Comment: I need to make proxy reserver in port 3128 to listening all traffic http and https to redirect right address for user. How Can I do it?

Comment: A proxy is either http/https/socks, the destination server protocol doesn't matter.